# Microsoft access changing data type when using a switch statement in ORDER BY in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-order-by, case

I currently have a table in a form that is populated by a query.I have drop-down in the form that I want to use to determine how a query gets sorted like this:

```
ORDER BY Switch(
[Forms]![Add/Find Programs]![sortField]="Program Title", programTitle,
[Forms]![Add/Find Programs]![sortField]="Department", department,
[Forms]![Add/Find Programs]![sortField]="Audience", audience,
[Forms]![Add/Find Programs]![sortField]="Method", method,
[Forms]![Add/Find Programs]![sortField]="Number", number)
```

This works how I want it to, except that when I select "`Number`" in my dropdown, it changes the data type of number to text somehow. The query sorts by `1,1,10,2,20,3...` etc. I have tried using `CInt()` and `Val()`. It still sorts like text. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have `switch` return a varying datatype. All branches must return the same datatype: here implicit conversion happens, and everything is converted to a string.

A simple workaround would be to separate the conditions into distinct ordering levels:

```
ORDER BY 
    IIF([Forms]![Add/Find Programs]![sortField]="Program Title", programTitle, null),
    IIF([Forms]![Add/Find Programs]![sortField]="Department", department, null),
    IIF([Forms]![Add/Find Programs]![sortField]="Audience", audience, null),
    IIF([Forms]![Add/Find Programs]![sortField]="Method", method, null)
    IIF([Forms]![Add/Find Programs]![sortField]="Number", number, null)
```